# Auto complete with comma with jQuery autocomplete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using below function to do `autocomplete` in `jQuery`. The function is little bit lengthy.

```
function fnBindAutoComplete(txtid, divnomatch, hdnid, hdnname) {
    jQuery("#" + txtid).autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var searchtext = jQuery("#txtUserName").val();
            var thiselem = jQuery("#" + txtid);
            var t = thiselem.val();
            var Qstr = thiselem.attr('Qstr');
            var type;
            var URL = window.location.href;
            URL = URL.replace("#b", "");
            if (window.location.search) { URL = URL.replace(window.location.search, ""); }
            if (frmUsers.optWorker.checked == true)
                type = "15";
            else if (frmUsers.optFacility.checked == true)
                type = "16";
            else
                type = "17";
            URL = URL.replace("#", "");
            URL = URL + "?t=" + t;
            URL = URL + "&rt=" + type;
            if (type == "16") {
                fnDisableUnitName();
            }
            if (type == "15") {
                document.getElementById("cbClinicalSuperUser").disabled = true;
                document.getElementById("cbClinicalSuperUser").style.opacity = '0.5';
            }

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: URL,
                success: function (data) {
                    try {
                        window["DataList"] = eval(data);
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        window["DataList"] = [];
                    }
                    if (typeof (DataList) === "undefined" || !jQuery.isArray(DataList) || DataList.length === 0 || !DataList[0].id) {
                        jQuery("#" + divnomatch).text("No Matches Found.");
                        jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "visible");
                        jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "inline");
                        jQuery("#" + hdnid).val("");
                        jQuery("#" + hdnname).val("");
                        response([]);
                    }
                    else {
                        jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("visibility", "hidden");
                        jQuery("#" + divnomatch).css("display", "none");
                        fnShowHideObjTR("trResultsForRAUsers", false);

                        response(jQuery.map(DataList, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.value,
                                value: item.value,
                                ID: item.id,
                                lNo: item.lNo,
                                eMail: item.eMail,
                                phyBUID: item.phyBUID
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    lblErrorMessage.innerHTML = "The server has not responded promptly to your \"Search as you Type\" queries. Please try again after a few minutes.";
                    fnShowHideObj("spanError", true);
                    response([]);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            document.getElementById(txtid).value = ui.item.value;
            document.getElementById(hdnid).value = ui.item.ID;
            document.getElementById(hdnname).value = ui.item.value;
            var userID = document.getElementById(hdnid).value;
            var userName = document.getElementById(hdnname).value;
            fnOnClickRA(userName, userID, userName, ui.item.lNo, ui.item.eMail || '', ui.item.phyBUID || 0);
        },
        open: function () {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function (event) {
            jQuery(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }

    });
}
```

The function `fnOnClickRA` is as below...

```
function fnOnClickRA(txt, usrid, username, lNo, eMail, phyBUID) {
    textchange=0;
    frmUsers.txtRAUsers.value=txt;
    textchange=1;
    frmUsers.hdnRAUserId.value=usrid ;
    frmUsers.hdnRAUserName.value=username;
    frmUsers.hdnBidLno.value= lNo;
    frmUsers.hdnEmail.value = eMail;
    fnGetCboBUSelected(phyBUID);
    if(eMail!="")
    {
        frmUsers.txtEMail.value=eMail;
        frmUsers.txtEMail.disabled=true;
        frmUsers.txtEMail.style.opacity = '0.5';
    }
    else
    {
       // frmUsers.txtEMail.value="";
        frmUsers.txtEMail.disabled=false;
        frmUsers.txtEMail.style.opacity = '1';
    }
    divResultsForRAUsers.innerText = "";
    fnShowHideObj("trResultsForRAUsers",false);
    fnShowHideObj("divNoMatchForRAUsers",false);
    bolNoPostBack = false;
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    frmUsers.txtRAUsers.focus();

    if (frmUsers.optFacility.checked==true)
        fnLoadUnitName(); 
    if (frmUsers.optWorker.checked == true)
    {
        document.getElementById("cbClinicalSuperUser").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("cbClinicalSuperUser").style.opacity = '1';
    }
}
```

I want to search the string even with comma in the search string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When I start typing in the Textbox, it filters out the names in the Textbox automatically. But when there is a comma in the string and start typing comma, the list that is showing disappears. This happens only with comma and only this needs to be addressed.

Comment: I have gone through this link - https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. But this option is not listed there....